# Error in Crystal Report and ASP on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I using VS 2008 and Crystal Report.
When I test my application in debug mode it work correctly .
but when I publish my project on IIS8 , it dos not work correctly
and I got bellowing error:

```
    This field name is not known.Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\ExamRecord_img {DAFBDC10-37ED-4DD5-8DCE-F9726C18E374}.rpt:
Error in formula  <Section_Visibility>.
'nextisnull({VR_CRSEXAMRECORD.CCL_ID})'
This field name is not known.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

this is my HTML code

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer Visible="true" ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" CssClass="rptViewer" />
```

and this is ASP code

```
ReportDocument doc;
DataSet ds = new DataSet("SampleDS");
// Fill ds from Oracle => select * from View
doc = new ReportDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports/" + rName + ".rpt"));
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tb in doc.Database.Tables)
{
    // Bind Tabels
}
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
```

Comment: after publish did you placed the reports folder in the publish code ?

Comment: Yes , I copied rpt files

Comment: did ya check the data source

Comment: because you need to choose the database you are expecting while executing the report

Comment: Yeah it's work .. thank you so mach

Comment: if it `actually` helped you please mark this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `Data Source` as one needs to choose the `database` he/she are expecting while executing the report